Android build fails due to 'CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.'
I can't build my Unity project and I don't know why. It seems to be the same problem all the time and I don't understand how to solve it. I tried everything, maybe someone here can help me:


I tried to take the project to another project a new one, didn't work. I tried everything that said online and nothing worked. I need to build it to Android, for Windows and iPhone it builds successfully.

You have tokens and API keys in your screenshot. Make sure these can be used publicly. See https://amplitude.com/docs/apis/keys-and-tokens

The actual error is in the previous message (the one starting with FAILURE). And even the one before it can contain some clues. And even the warnings can be related.

I had this problem for a while try launching unity hub with administrator if that doesnt work, goto Project Settings > Player > Android > Minimum api level. Mine was set above my phones and so it failed. For a while unistalling and reinstalling the editor would correct the gradle files and fix the error too.
